# Installing pfgornament?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, miktex, decorations, updating

Note: I have already searched through this site on how to do this but a lot of the things explained make little to no sense to me, I am a novice at this stuff so I was wondering if  could get a little more info.

I am using MiKTeX 2.9. I would love to be able to use the `pgfornament` package but I always get the following error:

> Errors:
>
> C:/Users/Chase/Documents/LaTeX Files/ornament trial.tex:3: LaTeX Error: File `pgfornament.sty' not found.

Is there a simple way to remedy this? I found a couple things about a "TDS Tree" and I am not sure what that is or how to use it. I have also found the packages folder in my MiKTeX folder with a lot of .tpm files. How can I add this package to MiKTeX?

Comment: According with the package documentation: `With
MiKTeX
, copy folder
pgfornament
into
C:\texmf\tex\latex
,
then run
MiKTeX Options
. In the
File name database
section,
click on
Refresh now
.`

Comment: There is no miktex package. You will have to install manually. Get the zip (http://www.altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/pgfornament/pgfornament.zip) unpack it, move all files that looks as you would need them to a folder `whatever/tex/latex/pgfornament` outside of miktex. Then go to miktex options, tab roots and add `whatever` as a new root.

Comment: Thanks guys, my problem was that the root wasn't set up, worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a localized issue concerning MikTeX root setup.

Comment: I had this issue and had to download and uncompress pgfornamaent, as in link above,second comment, and then move the pgfornament directory to miktex2.9->tex->latex directory. Then go to start->miktex->maintenance(admin)->miktex settings ->general -> refresh fndb